# When did Jo Grant meet the 11th Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

In my Character Encylopedia, it clearly states that Jo Grant met the 11th Doctor.

But when does she do this? I have seen all of the 11th Doctor episodes and I did not see her. **Is this simply a mistake in the book?**

Comment: These are good questions but are attracting downvotes because of poor spelling and grammar. I appreciate that English may not be your first language, but using the spell-check and making sure capitalisation rules are followed will go a long way.

Comment: @Richard Don't say "These are good question" and then lecture about poor grammar ;-)))

Comment: @randal'thor - Sometimes it takes a while to tease out the question but I like these. The OP has a genuine problem they're trying to solve, unlike a lot of questions.

Comment: @randal'thor - Damn you, autocorrect. Also damn you, crappy mobile SE interface.

Answer (score 11):

No, this isn't a mistake. This happens not in Doctor Who, but in the Sarah Jane Adventures, in the episode [Death of the Doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_the_Doctor):

Comment: Is this a spin off show like torch wood?

Comment: Yes, this one is a kids show.

Comment: The 10th doctor episodes The Stolen Earth and Journey's End feature some characters from The Sarah Jane Adventures (Sarah Jane Smith, Luke, Mr.Smith, K-9)